# Select rows with closest values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

```
          A   B       C
0  01:00:00  24  Andrew
1  01:00:00  28     Edd
2  01:00:00  12    Emma
3  01:00:00  18    Fred
4  02:00:00  17  Andrew
5  02:00:00  35     Edd
6  02:00:00  45    Emma
7  02:00:00  14    Fred
```

I want to select one row per each `A` group, with next conditions:

- Select the closest `B` value to 15 (in the case of `02:00:00`, the closest value to 15 is `14`).
- If there are two closest value to 15, select the greater of them (in the case of `01:00:00` select `18`).

Output should be:

```
          A   B       C
3  01:00:00  18    Fred
7  02:00:00  14    Fred
```

Comment: Sorry. I had a mistake in the code. Edited

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` here is to due with the special case *If there are two closest value to 15, select the greater of them*

```
df.sort_values('B',ascending=False).assign(New=(df.B-15).abs()).groupby(['A','New']).head(1).drop_duplicates('A',keep='last')
Out[486]: 
          A   B     C  New
3  01:00:00  18  Fred    3
7  02:00:00  14  Fred    1
```

Comment: In the case I didn’t need the second condition (If there are two closest value to 15, select the greater of them); how was the answer and which of two values would the program select?

Answer (score 2):

#### Fun with `min` and `key`

```
key = lambda x: (abs(x[1] - 15), -x[1])
f = lambda d: min(d.items(), key=key)[0]
df.loc[df.B.groupby(df.A).apply(f)]

          A   B     C
3  01:00:00  18  Fred
7  02:00:00  14  Fred
```

---

#### How about `np.lexsort`

```
df.iloc[np.lexsort(
    [-df.B, df.B.sub(15).abs()]
)].groupby('A').head(1)

          A   B     C
3  01:00:00  18  Fred
7  02:00:00  14  Fred
```

Comment: Quite frustrating, OP changed their question midway.

Comment: Good thing I don't pay attention until its way too late (-:

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to create a helper column, sort values and drop duplicates:

```
df['D'] = list(zip((df['B'] - 15).abs(), df['B'] - 15 < 0))

res = df.sort_values('D').drop_duplicates('A').drop('D', 1)

          A   B       C
4  02:00:00  17  Andrew
3  01:00:00  18    Fred
```

The idea is that you can sort by tuple column `D` by each element consecutively in ascending fashion, as this is how tuples are sorted in Python.

Answer (score 0):

We can use abs with 15.1 which would ensure that 16 is closer than 14 and so on.

Reindex and dropduplicates:

```
df = df.reindex((df['B']-15.1).abs().sort_values().index).drop_duplicates('A')
print(df)

          A   B     C
7  02:00:00  14  Fred
3  01:00:00  18  Fred
```

Or with iloc and 2 rows (also added a sort back function to get the lowest time)

```
newIndex = (df['B']-15.1).abs().sort_values().index
df = df.iloc[newIndex].drop_duplicates('A').sort_values(by='A')
```